# ios:Why is it that when I read an image and store it,its resolution drops

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use the `imageWithContentsOfFile:` method to read the image, and then I use `[UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageObj) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];` Stored images. Size does not change, but the resolution decreased. The size is 3189 x 5543, the original image resolution is 300, after storage was 72. I want to know why is like this, how to solve.

Comment: What do you mean resolution was 300 and then 72? Do you actually mean the DPI?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes.That's what it means.

Comment: DPI is irrelevant when working in iOS.

Comment: @rmaddy Well,thanks for your suggestions.